# apache cassandra join new node error by streaming error

Tags: java, cassandra

we use cassandra 3.11, now had a 7 nodes cluster.
now we join a new node(172.19.19.33) into this. in system.log,we got those messages:

```
ERROR StreamSession.java:593 [Stream #xxxx] Streaming error occured on session with peer 172.19.19.12
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LifecycleTransaction.update(LifecycleTransaction.java:340)
xxxxx
xxxx
at ort.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:317)
```

then we join once more, and use tcpdump catch the pacakges from 172.19.19.12 and this node, we found when 172.19.19.12 send a TCP ZeroWindow to 172.19.19.19.33 and then send TCP Flag RST right away。

how do we do for this.
what can i do for join a new node into this cluster.

I do set linux tcp_rmem and  use nodetool setstreamthrougput 32 and nodetool setinterdcstreamthrougput 32 for other nodes exclude 172.19.19.33. These methods does not fix this problem.
Then we create a new cluster, insert about 1TB data, then join new node to this cluster.
It look like normal and work good.

The 172.19.19.12 cluster had some problems before, at 70's day before, the cluster Schema vesionss had changed by one of the cluster's node restart, then we found the table was not created in all nodes, so we got the table data file and place it into seed's nodes (one of them),then the cluster become normal.